# Location of a file readed by a jar's method called by a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm having all kind of problems in a jsp page because I'm trying to read a .p12 file (google service account keyfile) and the method inside the jar file doesn't find it. I would try to be very descriptive about the problem (being my first question here I prefer to put too much information than too few).

The jsp file is called modDrive.jsp and it's in the WebContent folder a Dinamic Web Project.
I have added the miGoogle-drive.jar to the lib folder (and the source file to the WEB-INF/classes/miGoogle folder).

the modDrive.jsp makes this two calls to the DriveConnect static class in the jar file:

```
DriveConnect.setKEY_PATH("privatekey.p12");
DriveConnect.entrada("email@domain.net");
```

The problem is in the entrada method:

```
public static void entrada(String serviceAccountUser) {
        try {
          try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            GoogleCredential googleCredential = null;

                googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(KEY_FILE)
                        .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
                        .build();
```

The specific problem is that KEY_FILE (derived from the KEY_PATH previously setted) it's not found and obviously I get a file not found error... As you could imagine I have tried to put the .p12 file in all the folders and nothing, also I have tried to put a / as the first character of the KEY_PATH string and there's no way...

Any help would be greatly apreciated. :-)

Oh, yes, the previous code it's working perfectly as a cmd project (without the jar file), in that project the .p12 file it's in the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only passing in a relative file name will likely cause it to look in the working directory of the process, which can change between different runtime environments.

If you can pass an absolute path name in setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(), you can reliably obtain the absolute path this way:

```
new File(MyClass.class.getResource("privatekey.p12").toURI()).getAbsolutePath()
```

The "privatekey.p12" file name in this case is relative to MyClass, and you may need to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: It seems that setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File() doesn't accept Strings but Files, so I solved it this way:  
     <br/>
    KEY_FILE = new java.io.File(DriveConnect.class.getResource(kEY_PATH).toURI());     
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(KEY_FILE.getAbsoluteFile())     

It seems that now works (at least founds the file in the class folder. I understand for what you say that if I precede the URL with a /folder/subfolder/ I could store the key[s] in an independent folder from the class.  
  
Thanks! (and sorry for the multiple editing (first comment)

Comment: Good. But what if you have the file in src/main/resource/keys? How do you get access to the /WEB-INF/classes folder?